# jQuery concatenated with Gulp not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, concatenation

I'm running a Gulp task that concatenates and minifies all of my JavaScript files.

The idea is to concatenate all of the vendor files together, and then all my core application files together. Since my core app is dependent on JQuery, I'm loading the vendor file first like this:

```html
<script src="dist/app-vendor.js"></script>
<script src="dist/app-core.js"></script>
```

But for some reason it seems like JQuery isn't available by the time my app-core file loads:

> `app-core.js:7101 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

What am I doing wrong here??

```
        return gulp.src('scripts/' + name + '/*.js')
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(concat(name + '.js'))
                .pipe(rename(name + '.min.js'))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist', {'mode': '0777'}));
```

Comment: Are you sure jquery is actually in your `app-vendor` file?

Comment: @KyleLussier Yes - I can see the jquery source code in the outputted file.

Comment: I would suggest trying first `app-core`. Also, what's the output of `window.jQuery`?

Comment: @Veehmot window.jQuery is undefined. I'm thinking it may be an issue with the concatenation of jQuery with Gulp, but I'm not sure if theres a work around.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the relevant parts of your gulpfile.js code.

Comment: @Mark Updated the question - thanks